# QLineWidget returnPressed signal not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, signals-slots

I have a `QLineWidget` inside of `QWidget` that is a tab (`QTabWidget` 'page'), I'm trying to use the `returnPressed` signal, but it isn't working, it was working before but i completely changed the code structure and it's not anymore.

The application outputs `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_urlEntry_returnPressed()`

Widget class header: http://pastebin.com/GbMNmjUD
Widget class source: http://pastebin.com/chdkhBRy

Comment: Why don't you try explicitly connecting signal and slot?

Comment: Ok, this works, but I'm not sure if it is the best approach, and even if it is, i think it's important to understand what is going wrong with my current approach.

Comment: Can you attach your `.ui` file too?

Comment: I'm not using a .ui file, i created the UI with QT Design and used the source code as base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should have provided a minimal working example, not that bunch of code.

Second, if you simply used a debugger, you would notice that the warning comes after the second call to `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`. And that would mean that the `BrowserTab` object does not have a child named `urlEntry` with a signal named `returnPressed`. This happens because all control widgets you create become children of the `Browser` object passed in `BrowserTab::setupUi` and not the `BrowserTab`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating new widgets in the tab as children of `Browser`? Use `this` instead of `Browser`.
In your code child elements of tab belongs to parent of the tab.